# Does a creature sharing a soulmeld benefit from a master's binding and invested essentia?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, familiars, animal-companions, mount, meldshaping

The benefit of the feat **Share Soulmeld** says

> At your option, any soulmeld shaped by you and currently affecting you can also affect your familiar, animal companion, or [presumably special] mount [like a paladin's [special mount]](http://www.systemreferencedocuments.org/resources/systems/pennpaper/dnd35/soveliorsage/paladin.html#paladin-special-mount). The creature in question must remain within 5 feet of you to receive the benefit. If the creature leaves this radius of effect, it loses the benefits of the soulmeld until such time as it returns within 5 feet. (*Magic of Incarnum* 41)

Does the shared soulmeld's effect include extending to the familiar, companion, or special mount essentia invested in that soulmeld by the creature's master, or does the shared soulmeld only have its basic effect, the soulmeld needing essentia invested into it by the creature with whom it's being shared? Further, does a soulmeld that's bound to a chakra extend the additional benefits for being so bound to the creature with whom the soulmeld's being shared?

For example, Jalas, an arctic snow elf incarnate 2/wizard 1 that possesses the feat Share Soulmeld, shapes at the beginning of the day the soulmeld *dissolving spittle* (*MoI* 64-5) and opts to share the soulmeld *dissolving spittle* with Fun, his lemming familiar. Later, on his turn Jalas takes a swift action to invest 1 point of essentia into the soulmeld *dissolving spittle*. If Fun is within 5 ft. of Jalas, when Fun employs the soulmeld *dissolving spittle*, on a successful ranged touch attack, will Fun's *spittle* attack deal 1d6 or 2d6 points of acid damage?

A few adventures later, Jalas, now an incarnate 3/wizard 3, has taken the feat Extra Familiar (*Dragon* #280 62) to become the master of another familiar, a rat. At the beginning of the day Jalas shapes then binds to his crown the soulmeld *soulspark familiar* (*MoI* 86) so that Jalas gains the service of a lesser soulspark (*MoI* 197-8). Jalas opts to share the soulmeld *soulspark familiar* with his familiars, Fun the lemming and Steamboat the rat. When his familiars are within 5 ft. of Jalas, do Fun and Steamboat each gain the service of a least soulspark familiar (*MoI* 197) or a lesser soulspark familiar?

***Note:*** Assume that the DM has ruled that a soulspark familiar isn't, for the purposes of the feat Share Soulmeld, itself an actual, for-reals, wizard-style familiar, therefore preventing Jalas from bringing forth a pretty large number of least soulspark familiars by sharing the soulspark familiar *soulmeld with each least soulspark familiar brought forth by the* soulspark familiar *soulmeld!*

Answer (score 2):

My reading is that, if they intended that Share Soulmeld *only* shares the basic effect of the soulmeld, they would *say that*. As it is, the soulmeld you have affects your companion—and so anything that soulmeld is doing for you, it also does for the companion. That includes benefits it supplies for your investing essentia in it, and chakra binds.

In most cases, this is kind of necessary to make the feat worthwhile. Basic effects are very, well, basic. On the other hand, *dissolving spittle* and *soulspark familiar* are two examples of how this can go awry. But it’s not really all that different from sharing spells with a familiar; at least the incarnate had to spend a feat on it.

Comment: @BenBarden in a now-deleted Comment raised the prospect that I've misread the extent of Share Soulmeld, saying that the feat only allows soulmelds to be shared with one of the listed creatures at a time. Did you want to address that controversy, or is that beyond the question's scope, or does that make the feat just too much of a downer to even consider?

Comment: @HeyICanChan Beyond scope as far as I’m concerned

Comment: Asked [here](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/101258/8610).